# How to make one section snap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I only want one section of the page to be full screen. Everything else can scroll as usual. So in this case only div one needs to remain full page. The CSS already has the page at full screen but I only want it to be viewed at full screen so it snaps if it is not completely in view.

I have used scroll snapping and it works for multiple sections not the one. The height is already 100vh for the section.

```html
<div class="container">
    <section><Div class="one"></Div></section>
    <section><Div class="two"></Div></section>
    <section><Div class="three"></Div></section>
    <section><Div class="four"></Div></section>
    <section><Div class="five"></Div></section>
</div>
```

Comment: whatever section you want to use the whole screen ,use `height:100vh` for that particular section

Comment: I believe you are looking for [CSS Scroll Snapping](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)